# Clicking the follow link from the review queue does nothing

Tags: bug, status-completed, follow-post

I was doing some "First Post" reviews and found that clicking the follow link does nothing there. I went to the post directly and was able to click follow there. I think this is a bug.

---

July 21, 2020: The current behavior seems to be that clicking follow *will run* the appropriate functions so that you will be following the post. The popup notices will trigger, but not always if you try toggling by clicking the link multiple times. As for user experience, the link text does not change, so you have no confidence that it worked.

---

July 26, 2020 -  In moderator review on mobile Chrome the follow link did not work at all. Both "you are following" and "you are no longer following" popups came up in sequence and the post was not added to my followed list.