# Anonymous users get no notification when attempting to follow a post from a review queue

Tags: bug, status-review, review, anonymous, follow-post

When checking out the review-queue item created by an anonymous edit of mine, I noticed that clicking on the "follow" link does nothing. No console messages, no confirmation, no pop-up. Outside the review queue, clicking brings up a pop-up asking me to create an account.

[image: Low Quality Posts review with the "follow" link circled]

This happens in all queues, so here's a random (likely-autoflagged) [LQP review item](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/51506). Clicking on "Share" gives a pop-up with a share link, clicking on "Improve this question" the editor. It's just the "Follow" link which is inexplicably nonfunctional.

The same behavior is observed when attempting to click the "cite" link ([example review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/1405297)). While the titles look similar, [Clicking the follow link from the review queue does nothing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350813/clicking-the-follow-link-from-the-review-queue-does-nothing) (and the question it's a duplicate of) are different as those are for users who *could* follow outside the review queue. The expected behavior for an anonymous visitor attempting to follow is a pop-up inviting them to join the site.

Windows 10 Home, Chrome

Comment: If a reader is wondering how anonymous users are linked to the review system: it's usually from right after they edit a post anonymously; they're linked to the edit review item.